# Cannot seem to set default option for Select Option; using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I did some research but I just don't understand what's happening.  When the page loads.. it has a blank `<option>` selected as default.

When I initially click the dropdownbox and the menu pops down.. I get the options:

1. BLANK
2. User
3. Moderator
4. Admin

then when i select something.. only

1. User
2. Moderator
3. Admin are available for choosing

   User
     Moderator
     Admin

JS

```
$scope.formData = {
    role: 'Select Role...',
    userName: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    clientId: '',
    clientName: 'Select Client...',
    clientShowId: '',
    clientShowName: 'Select Show...'
};

//Role DropDown Click
$scope.roleSelect = function (role) {
    $scope.formData.role = '--- Select Role---'
    $scope.formData.role = role;

    //reset other dropdowns
    $scope.formData.clientName = '---Select Client...';
    $scope.formData.clientShowName = 'Select Show...';
};
```

VIEW

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.role" ng-change="roleSelect(formData.role)" ng-init="formData.role = '--- Please Select---'">                     
    <option value="User">User</option>
    <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use ng-options on select element. the directive is made specifically for the situation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you add the default option: `ng-init="formData.role = '--- Please Select---'"` is not the way to do.

It should be an option with an empty value.

You get an *empty* value when the list is loaded because in the model, `$scope.formData.role` is equal to `'Select Role...'` and this value does not match any value from the list.

With:

```
$scope.formData = {
    role: '',
    // ...
}
```

and:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.role">
    <option value="">--- Please Select---</option>
    <option value="User">User</option>
    <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```

The initial value of `formData.role` will then match with the value of '--- Please Select---'

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u82za4r/3/)**

Comment: i tried this as well but that didn't work neither... something about the ng-model is forcing a blank as the first item

Comment: ah this is actually the best answer as to WHY.  ty

Comment: You're welcome:) Once you get comfortable with it, you could look at `ngOptions` which is another way to go (and particularly useful if you need to select something other than string values)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this in your view between the  tags:
Try setting your role as 'defaultVal' and then putting that in the

```
<option value="'defaultVal'">--- Please Select---</option>
```

Basically - you need to match the initial role setting to the value attribute in the Option tag.

Comment: i actually tried this as well and that didn't work neither...

something about the ng-model is forcing a blank at the first item..

Answer (score 1):

ng-model with select shows the default option only when the value in ng-model matches with the one of the elements in the options.

so you need to use it like this,

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.role" ng-init="formData.role = '--- Please Select---'" ng-change="roleSelect(formData.role)">                     
    <option>--- Please Select---</option>
    <option value="User">User</option>
    <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
  </select>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zr89xjvxnKYUt73MjkVe?p=preview) link for the same.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the above answers, if you're interested in using [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), here is a *simplified* way to do so with a initial `<option>` element...

```
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = ['User', 'Moderator', 'Admin'];
});
```

---

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="o as o for o in options"> 
    <option value="">--- Please Select---</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/747cd1v1/) - working demo